# GetElementById from node object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the an html code which resembles this:

```
<div id="abc">
    <div class="class1">some data</div>
    <div class="class2">
        <input type="number" id="row1-id1" />
        <input type=number" id="row1-id2" />
    </div>
    <div class="class2">
        <input type="number" id="row2-id1" />
        <input type=number" id="row2-id2" />
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to read all input tag and create a list from it. The input tag needs to be inside the `div` with class `class2` which in turn should be under `#abc`.
I have written the following code to read them.

```
var rows = document.getElementById('abc').getElementsByClassName('class2');
for (var i=0;i<rows.length;i++) {
    var id1 = rows[i].getElementById('row'+(i+1)+'-id1);
    var id2 = rows[i].getElementById('row'+(i+1)+'-id2);
    .......
    .......
}
```

Now when i try to do the above i get an error saying 'getElementById is not a function'.

How do i access the element with specific Id inside the node?

Comment: I would check the console for any errors.

Comment: you are missing a `"` in `<input type=number" id="row1-id2" />`

Comment: wouldn't something like `document.querySelectorAll( '#abc .class2 input' )` be simpler to access all input fields?

Comment: just **always** use `document.getElementById` - because ID's must be unique to a document, therefore there's no need for any other elements to have a `getElementById` method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of fix the mistakes in your code. Your missing 2 `"` in your html, and 2 `'` in your javascript.

Second, then use `querySelector` like: `rows[i].querySelector('#row' + (i + 1) + '-id1')`. Then your code works fine.

**Demo**

```js
var rows = document.getElementById('abc').getElementsByClassName('class2');
for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
  var id1 = rows[i].querySelector('#row' + (i + 1) + '-id1');
  var id2 = rows[i].querySelector('#row' + (i + 1) + '-id2');
  console.log(id1)
}
```

```html
<div id="abc">
  <div class="class1">some data</div>
  <div class="class2">
    <input type="number" id="row1-id1" />
    <input type="number" id="row1-id2" />
  </div>
  <div class="class2">
    <input type="number" id="row2-id1" />
    <input type="number" id="row2-id2" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Please Note that since Id's should be unique, then you can always just use `var id1 = document.getElementById('row' + (i + 1) + '-id1');`